# Angular events duration

Tags: angular, performance

I need to create an Angular web app and I need to log some performance time related data:

- time between the button click and API call is fired
- time between the API call is fired and the API returns the response
- time between the API returns the response and data is render

How should I achieve this? What technologies should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be using session storage. Get the time when the button click event executes, the time right before api call, the time in your first 'map' or 'subscribe' from the api call, and then use the function ngAfterViewInit() to know it has re-rendered.

first is button click...

```
buttonClicked() {
   const nowMilliseconds = Date.now();
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('button', nowMilliseconds);
   this.myService.callApi()
      .subscribe(response => {
           const responseMilliseconds = Date.now();
           window.sessionStorage.setItem('response', responseMilliseconds);
           // make sure to set some value here that will make the screen have to re-render
       });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   const renderedNow = Date.now();
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('rendered', renderedNow);
}
```

And in your service...

```
callApi() {
   const callingApi = Date.now();
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('apicall', callingApi);

   return this.httpService.get('myApiEndpoint');
}
```

Then to get the values after everything is done you can look in your developer tools and look at the milliseconds and calculate the difference, or you can get them within the angular code with window.sessionStorage.getItem('apicall'); ... replace apicall with the other strings to get the other values.

Comment: this helped me a lot. Thanks. My only problem is that if I have 1000 entries with images returned by the API, rendering takes longer, but ngAfterViewInit() returns the time before all the images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [performance.now()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now) API, like:

```js
function fire() {
  // Init
  var moments = {};
  moments.evt1 = performance.now();
  moments.evt2 = performance.now();
  setTimeout(function() {
    moments.evt3 = performance.now();
    // Get times
    var results = [];
    results.push((moments.evt2 - moments.evt1) + 'ms');
    results.push((moments.evt3 - moments.evt1) + 'ms');
    // Show results
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = results.join(', ');
  }, 500);
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="fire()">Click me</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```